# Python Loop - Continue asking until correct answer is inputted

Tags: python

I am doing a fitness program in Python and I need to collect information about the user.
The rest of the code works fine except when collecting gender.

I want the code to repeat the question if the answer M, F, m or f is not entered. However when I run this code, even when I type in M, F, m or f, it says "Please enter M for Male or F for Female".

```
gender = input("What is your gender? M/F: ")
while gender != "M" or "F" or "m" or "f":
    print("Please enter M for Male or F for Female.")
    gender = input("What is your gender? M/F: ")
```

I have tried replacing `!=` with `is not` with no success.

Comment: Because `gender != "M" or "F" or "m" or "f"` is *always* `True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right approach:

```
while gender not in ("M","F","m","f"):
```

when you check `or "m"`, "m" is True as it has value in the string and therefore it will always be true.

You also could do :

```
while gender != "M" or gender != "F" or gender != "m" or gender != "f":
```