# IF inside a TRY? (Python 3.6)

Tags: python

I have a use a `try`/`except` block to prompt the user for an input. My problem is that it always prints "Perfect" no matter what the number of `number_disks`. What is the problem with my code?

```
number_disks = -2

try:
      number_disks > 0 and number_disks <= 8
      print("Perfect")
except:
      print("the number of disks is between 1 and 8, try again!")
      number_disks = input(int("what is the number of disks?\n"))
```

Comment: You forgot the `if` in your `if`.

Comment: I'm also curious what exception you expect to be thrown.

Comment: `try` `except` blocks are not for conditionals, they are for catching errors that might otherwise crash your program. You should use an `if` statement instead.

Comment: The ordering of statements in your code is most peculiar!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44646304/2564301 for a number of fixes.

Comment: I want to use try/expect to make sure that the user input in an integer

Comment: I think we can't help you much here in the comments. There's so much wrong with this code. Not knowing how `if`/`else` is used, not knowing how to properly catch exceptions, the weird ordering of statements... You need to work through a Python tutorial.

Comment: @FreshmanUCSD You have *two* coding situations: (1) see that the input is an integer; (2) repeat until you get a valid input.  Solve one at a time; each technique is covered quite well in on-line resources.

Comment: Also, note that you have *not* used a `try` to check for integer input: there is no `input` or `int` operation in your `try` clause.  Back up to the tutorials or class materials ... solve one item at a time, *then* go to the next.  It's called "incremental programming" -- and it's not just for beginners!

Comment: Thank you Prune and folks here for help!

Answer (score 1):

It should be :

```
if number_disks > 0 and number_disks <= 8
  print("Perfect")
```

If you want the print to occure given that conditional, and not always

If wanted to use an exception perhaps:

```
if number_disks > 0 and number_disks <= 8
   raise Exception();
```

Which then wouldn't do the print statement if the exception occured

Comment: Consider `if 0 < number_disks <= 8`.

Comment: So is it supposed to print if between those numbers or ouside of them ?

Comment: @timgeb's condition is a [chained comparison](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). It means if `0 < number_disks`, and `number_disks <= 8`.